# SharePoint Server 2013 Multiple search index components in one single server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I would like to know if it's possible to have 2 or more index components (not index partitions) in one single front-end server. I looked for the answer for hours but with no success. Also, kindly provide me with technet/msdn article if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, in dev scenarios you install all components on one machine. But just because something can be done it doesn't mean it should. Search is very resource intensive and active crawls will affect ability to serve http pages.Another point to look out for is not to run search components on same server as Distributed Cache as search will eat up memory and force eviction of cache.